# Access denied on main url

Tags: .net, url, iis, access-denied

When I try to enter **`my.domain.com`** I get

> 403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.

But when I enter **`my.domain.com/Login.aspx`** it works fine.

Where do I redirect the main url to the login page, in web.config or in IIS? Or is there a better solution to this?

Comment: Do you have index.aspx or index.html?

Comment: No, I don't. Should I rename my Login page to Index? Because the login page acts as the index page.

Comment: Yaa.. You may need to do that. Please try that and get back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add your Login.aspx to your default document of IIS.

Below are the steps to do so

**Step - 1**
Select your wesbite IIS
[image]

**Step - 2**
Add `"Login.aspx"` here 
[image]

Comment: Works perfect..and with least amount of work for me =)

Answer (score 0):

There should be a page under the root folder, by default the name of the page can be (Default.aspx, Index.aspx, Index.html etc)

And in the web.config set login url as follows,

```
<system.web>    
    <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms loginUrl="~/Login.aspx" timeout="45" protection="All">
    </forms>
    </authentication>
</system.web>

<location path="Default.aspx">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```